# WordPress Child Theme Header.php Not Functioning

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I carefully followed the walkthrough here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes 
and fully copied my parent header.php in to my child theme.

The child theme showed up in my WP dashboard as expected and I was able to activate it. The customised child style.css was implemented as expected.

In my child header.php I call on three includes, found in my child theme's includes directory, using the 'include_once' method as such:

```
<!-- Variables -->
<?php include_once('includes/vars.php'); ?>
<!-- /Variables -->
<!-- Social menu -->
<?php include_once('includes/social-menu.php'); ?>
<!-- /Social menu -->
<!-- LiveChat Button -->
<?php include_once('includes/livechat.html'); ?>
<!-- /LiveChat Button -->
```

Despite this, my header fails to produce any of the three includes. I'm wondering if there's something I'm overlooking or if perhaps I've incorrectly implemented the child header.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the extended path to your child theme's folder, assuming your "includes" folder is in the child theme directory:

```
wp-content/themes/[child-theme-name]/includes/
```

Comment: Upon that recommendation I changed my code to:

..> <?php include_once('wp-content/themes/responsive-child/includes/social-menu.php'); ?>

but that had no effect.

Comment: Have you inspected the resulting HTML page in either Firebug or Chrome? Maybe they are being included but they're hidden behind something. What browser are you using?

Comment: Oh man! What a doofus. I didn't even consider that. Yes, I F12'd the page and they are being obscured. So it looks like I've got styling issues and not include issues. Thanks for helping point out the obvious.

Comment: LOL... no problem. Sometimes it takes bouncing these things off of somebody else. I like the name, BTW :-)